# Start ACTION_SEND Intent from Library

Tags: android, android-intent, android-library

I want to start an intent for sending email with clients. But `context.startActivity` does not work in library project. Can you help me? Thanks

```
public class email {
private Context context;

public email(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public void send(String to, String subject, String body) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("message/rfc822");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);

    try {
        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "sending..."));
    }
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

    }
}
```

OK. Logcat says:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test.MainActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

Comment: Please add more information, such as your code, and what error message you are given that leads to to think that it "does not work".

Comment: ok, maybe ActivityNotFound for your intent. perfect.

Comment: in main activity it works but in library it does not.

Comment: "But context.startActivity does not work in library project" -- yes, it does, if `context` is a valid `Context`. However, you have not bothered to explain what "does not work" means. You have not bothered to log anything to LogCat if you get an `ActivityNotFoundException`. You have not bothered to show us how you are attempting to use this `email` Java class. This is not [a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and so it will be difficult for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself:
When I wanted to pass the `context` to constructor of `email` class I used `getApplicationContext()` and when I changed it to `this` it worked.

Comment: its good that you found a workaround by yourself. But your solution is not good. I guess you are using this class from an activity. So using "this" which is a ActivityContext, instead of  "getApplicationContext()" has solved the problem. But your constructor is actually taking a Context reference. So anybody else can create it's object with a ApplicationContext and your code will allow him to create it. later they will get exception when they call send(). So its a better idea to add a flag in the intent instead of relying on ActivityContext strictly.

Comment: Suppose if you use this method from a broadcast receiver then it will throw the same exception.

Comment: When I add the flag you said, Logcat says: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

Usually I use

```
getActivity().getBaseContext()
```

in most instances, but if you get stuck, here's another way.

You can define a abstract baseactivity and then have all your activities implement it, or at least the one from which you will need a context reference in it children.

`public abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity 
...
    private static Context baseContext;
...

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    BaseApplication.baseContext = getApplicationContext();
```

...

```
public static Context getMyContext() {
    return BaseApplication.baseContext;
}
```

`

You can then call getMyContext() in other places a bit easier, but FIRST only use this if getActivity().getBaseContext() doesn't work.

I'd need more specifics on your code, like from what type of activity it's being called, etc. to give an exact answer.

Answer (score 0):

add `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` before starting the activity. you need to set this Flag whenever you are trying to switch to an Activity but your origin place is not an Activity itself.